# Postgresql CONSTRAINT on column to global set of string/text values

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I have a set of multiple tables in a single database which is roughly using a table inheritance pattern. The "class" is stored where required in a given table as a varchar column. Most tables have only one possible value but there are a few tables that can validly have any value. I also have a configuration table that basically lists all valid "class" names.

For the sake of maintainability and data consistency, I want to be able to impose a constraint on the various tables that can prevents operations from inserting records that reference a "class" that doesn't exist but I want the valid list to be "global" to the DB and I want it to be as performant as possible.

My intuition is to apply the constraint with something like `class_name IN ('car', 'bike', 'fruit')`. So far I've explored trying a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` with a subquery from the configuration table which isn't valid SQL and tried getting a stored `FUNCTION` to return the required set but that doesn't seem to be a kind of return type PostgreSQL functions support. I also tried assigning the set to a "global" config variable via `ALTER DATABASE db SET abc.xyz = 1` but again, a set of values for IN doesn't appear to be valid SQL.

I know I could achieve this with a `FOREIGN KEY` but that means deletion of the configuration records impacts the values stored in the other tables and I'm concerned about performance.

I'm aware of the `ENUM` data type, but I want to store the "class" name as a varchar because text is just easier to work with.

Is there an approach that I might have missed that could be both "global" (i.e. maintained in one location in the DB only), stored as plain text and relatively performant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a domain with a check constraint:

```
create domain class_name_domain as text
  constraint check_name check (value in ('car', 'bike'));
  
create table the_table
(
  id         integer primary key, 
  class_name class_name_domain
);
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need. I've marked it as the correct answer even though I haven't tested it because reading the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdomain.html) indicates it does just what I need for this purpose and is SQL standard, not just PostgreSQL. If only I knew what was the right keyword to search for. Thanks!

Comment: Further feedback, after testing it seems that there is a little bit of a complication when updating a domain. But otherwise seems to do just what I needed. For future folk, it seems you need to drop the constraint (not the domain) then reapply it to update the check condition. i.e.
`ALTER DOMAIN class_name_domain DROP CONSTRAINT check_name;
ALTER DOMAIN class_name_domain ADD CONSTRAINT check_name CHECK(VALUE IN ('car', 'bike', 'boat', 'rocket'));`